# ¿Cómo llevar la información de algunas filas a columnas en R, de manera de quedar un id por fila?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con dos columnas: id y categoría.

```
id  <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6)
categoria <- c("A","B","C","B","A","C","A","C","A","B","C","B")
df <- data.frame(id,categoria)
```

A veces un id aparece en más de una fila, asociado a diferentes categorías. ¿Existe la forma de mover las filas correspondientes al mismo id como nuevas columnas, de manera de que la información de cada id quede en una misma fila? El resultado deseado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar llevarlo de long a wide, para esto puedes usar el paquete `tidyr`, pero te hace falta el contador de cada categoría.

El código sería:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(n=paste0("cat.",1:n())) %>%
 spread(key = n, value = categoria)
```

En tu caso, el id, está ordenado, pero si no estuviese podrías usar un arrange (`df %>% arrange(id)`), esto debido a que se tiene que crear un contador por categoría.

El resultado obtenido.

```
     id cat.1 cat.2 cat.3
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     B     C    
2     2 B     A     C    
3     3 A     C     NA   
4     4 A     NA    NA   
5     5 B     C     NA   
6     6 B     NA    NA
```